# TensorFlow Serving RAM Usage

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm having trouble finding specific information in the documentation regarding how models are saved and loaded in TensorFlow Serving and possible differences when running on CPU vs GPU.

For serving multiple models (and one or more versions of each), one general workflow is:

- Train models
- Save frozen models (*tf.saved_model.simple_save*)
- Creates directory structure containing

  - saved_model.pb
  - variables/variables.data
  - variables/variables.index
- Point to models and versions in *config.conf*

I am currently running inference on CPU and loading many models at once which is eating up RAM much more quickly than expected. The saved model is relatively small on disk, but when TF Serving loads the model into memory it is nearly an order of magnitude larger. A single **200MB** saved_model on disk turns into **1.5GB** in RAM, greatly limiting the number of models that can be loaded.

## Questions:

- Is this behavior (larger memory footprint in RAM) expected?
- Is there a difference in how TF Serving uses Memory on CPU vs GPU?
- Would we be able to load more models by doing inference on GPU?

#### Loosely related search results:

- [Eager load the entire model to estimate memory consumption of Tensorflow Serving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56012618/eager-load-the-entire-model-to-estimate-memory-consumption-of-tensorflow-serving)
- https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1215

Comment: I had issues with memory consumption too. Though you don't seem to use frozen models produced by `freeze_graph.py`, this script was the cause in my case. Maybe somebody would be interested in my experience https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036745/895077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's expected.

No it won't matter CPU/GPU

You're probably going to fit fewer in GPU memory, due to having less GPU memory than system memory.

Comment: So the only remedy to fit more models in memory is to decrease model size? Any other possible solutions?

Comment: You could consider using the cloud, where memory is cheap and readily available.